# Really slow pagespeed ranking - Angular 15 Server Side Rendering

Tags: angular, iis, server-side-rendering

I am getting really slow pagespeed ranking below 20 for some pages, as a result I lazyloaded modules, with little difference in pagespeed test, i decided to lazyload all the modules. And i have significantly reduced app.module.ts imports and components as a result. By the way a simple page that contains text only doesn't score more than 50.

[image]

But when i build app for server side rendering main.js file is still huge. At now `9mb`. Lazyloading doesn't seem to reduce that. Is there some problem in my approach why pagespeed performance isn't being improved! Additionally i run sourcemap combined size is showing `3mb`.

SSR build command

```
"build:ssr": "ng build --configuration=production --output-hashing=all && ng run myApp:server",
```

tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,

  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },

}
```

`

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "myApp": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myApp/browser",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/ads.txt",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/google43d412fda361808c.html",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css",
              "node_modules/cropperjs/dist/cropper.min.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
              "node_modules/@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart/picker.css",
              "src/styles/styles.css",
              "src/styles/main.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js"
            ],
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "sourceMap": false,
            "optimization": false,
            "namedChunks": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "10kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "serviceWorker": false,
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error"
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myApp:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config",
              "src/manifest.json",
              "src/sitemap.xml"
            ]
          }
        },
        "server": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/myApp/server",
            "main": "server.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
            "optimization": false,
            "sourceMap": true,
            "extractLicenses": false,
            "vendorChunk": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false
            },
            "development": {}
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve-ssr": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:ssr-dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "myApp:server:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "myApp:server:production"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "prerender": {
          "builder": "@nguniversal/builders:prerender",
          "options": {
            "routes": [
              "/"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production",
              "serverTarget": "myApp:server:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:development",
              "serverTarget": "myApp:server:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    },
    "myApp-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "myApp:serve:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "myApp:serve:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

Server.ts file

```
import 'zone.js/node';

import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { parseString } from 'xml2js';
import 'localstorage-polyfill';
import * as path from 'path';

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
const compression = require('compression');

const xmlFilePath = 'sitemap.xml';
let xmlData = null;
// let sitemapData = null;

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(data): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/my-app/browser');
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';
  let sitemapData = data;

  // compress dist folder

  server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
  server.use(compression()) //compressing dist folder 

  // Our Universal express-engine (found @ https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/main/modules/express-engine)
  server.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));

  server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // Handle URL-encoded data
  server.use(bodyParser.json());
  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', distFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // Function to make a GET request

  server.get('/api/appleauth', (req, res) => {
    // Handle the GET request here
    console.log("get request done");
    res.send('GET request received');
  });
  // POST request handler

  server.post('/api/appleauth', (req, res) => {
    // Handle the incoming POST request
    console.log("start post");

    res.redirect('/login?applecode=' + req.body.id_token);


  });


  server.post('/api/appleauth/connect', (req, res) => {
    // Handle the incoming POST request


    res.redirect('/einstellungen?appleconnectcode=' + req.body.id_token);


  });

  // All regular routes use the Universal engine
  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    if (req.originalUrl.includes("/pflanze")) {

      var urlSplit = req.originalUrl.split("/");
      var splitCount = urlSplit.length;
      if (splitCount > 3) {
        var plantId = urlSplit[splitCount - 2];
        var plantName = urlSplit[splitCount - 1];

        var currentUrlId = "/pflanze/" + plantId;


        if (sitemapData != null) {



          const urls = sitemapData?.urlset?.url || [];


          console.error('Error parsing XML:', urls);

          const searchString = currentUrlId;

          const foundItem = urls.find(item => item.loc[0].includes(searchString));

          if (foundItem != null) {
            var correctUrl = foundItem.loc[0];

            var correctSplit = correctUrl.split("/");
            var correctCount = correctSplit.length;
            var finalName = correctSplit[correctCount - 1];

            if (finalName.toLowerCase() == plantName.toLowerCase()) {
              res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });

            }
            else {
              res.redirect(301, correctUrl);

            }
          }
          else {
            // res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
            res.redirect(301, 'https://my-app.de/video4/' + searchString);

          }


        }
        else {
          res.redirect(301, 'https://my-app.de/video2');

        }
      }
    } else {
      res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
    }

  });

  return server;
}




function run(data): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4200;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app(data);
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = mainModule && mainModule.filename || '';

fs.readFile(xmlFilePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error reading XML file:', err);
  } else {
    xmlData = data;

    parseString(xmlData, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        // res.redirect(301, 'https://my-app.de/video3');

        console.error('Error parsing XML:', err);
      } else {

        if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
          run(result);
        }

      }
    });

    // }
  }
});



export * from './src/main.server';
```

Comment: You need to provide more info, `tsconfig` file is not enough to figure out what's going on there. Providing webpack config would also help. Also why do you need source maps on production?

Comment: @Eldar I don't have a custom webpack file, i added angular.json file. Anything else i should add?

Comment: don't use server-side rendering... that'll slow down things.  If you're doing that for SEO, realize that Google can crawl SPA's just fine.  Just make sure to use hash-style routing so each page can be linked and bookmarked.  For site-links, you can use "ShareURLs" which can be used to render pages statically (at first, anyway)... makes it easier for site's like FB to grab content.

Comment: Probably because you're bundling all of jquery and bootstrap. Just use [ng-bootstrap](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap) instead

Comment: @samwu Why would Microsoft of all people help OP find the root cause?

Comment: @Pieterjan can't trust that thirdparty library.

Comment: This tool should help you analyze the issue: [Microsoft Network Monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865).

Comment: @browsermator do you have experience with CSR SPA's that list for SERP? Our page only ever started to really list on google after we implemented SSR and i'm talking about after 2 years! Also meta tags identification wouldn't work before SSR

Comment: besides that implementing SSR was and still is a pain to work with

Comment: no experience there myself.  You might consult google about what they prefer for whatever "SERP" is.  I have noticed that links posted on facebook need the "ShareURL" version of a page I created or it wouldn't pull the images.   Those ShareURLs are links to non-JS versions of the pages (so server-side rendered).  Once landed on the JS kicks in.  (jQuery pulls from server via Ajax for future links) Once I switch that site over to angular front-end I suppose I'll need to use SSR then.  I haven't used Angular's SSR yet, but I'd guess it does the same and only initial load would be slow.

Comment: So the shareURL versions build the header meta-tags dynamically....